# Retornar registros de uma tabela cuja chave esta referenciada em outra CakePHP 3

Tags: php, cakephp, orm, cakephp-3

Estou utilizando o **ORM** nativo do **CakePHP 3** para recuperar os registros da tabela produto (através do ID) juntamente com os registros que o referencia com o seguinte método:

```
public function view($id)
{
    if($this->request->is('get'))
    {
        $product = $this->Products->get($id, [
            'contain' => ['Stores', 'Bookings', 'ProductFeatures', 'ProductMedias']
        ]);
        $this->set('product', $product);

        $bannerType = 2;
        $bannersQuantity = 1;
        $fullBanners = $this->Search->listAllBanners($bannerType, $bannersQuantity);
        $this->set('fullBanners', $fullBanners);

        $logged = $this->Auth->user();
        $this->set('logged', $logged);

        $this->set('pageTitle', $product['product_name'].' - Stores');
    }
}
```

Esta sendo retornado basicamente todos os registros que necessito porém como faço para retornar cada **registro da tabela features referenciado na tabela product_features**

**Tabelas do banco:**

```
CREATE TABLE products (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  product_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  store_id INT NOT NULL,
  sub_category_id INT NOT NULL,
  quantity INT NOT NULL,
  sold INT NOT NULL,
  description VARCHAR(1000),
  price DECIMAL(7,2) NOT NULL,
  old_price DECIMAL(7,2) NOT NULL,
  visited INT NOT NULL,
  thumbnail VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  status INT NOT NULL,
  created DATETIME,
  modified DATETIME,
  FOREIGN KEY store_key (store_id) REFERENCES stores(id),
  FOREIGN KEY sub_category_key (sub_category_id) REFERENCES sub_categories(id)
);

CREATE TABLE sub_categories (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  sub_category_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  category_id INT NOT NULL,
  created DATETIME,
  modified DATETIME,
  FOREIGN KEY category_key (category_id) REFERENCES categories(id)
);

CREATE TABLE features (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  feature_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  created DATETIME,
  modified DATETIME
);

CREATE TABLE product_features (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  feature_value VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  feature_id INT NOT NULL,
  product_id INT NOT NULL,
  created DATETIME,
  modified DATETIME,
  FOREIGN KEY feature_key (feature_id) REFERENCES features(id),
  FOREIGN KEY product_key (product_id) REFERENCES products(id)
);
```

**Resultado do var_dump($product)**

```
object(App\Model\Entity\Product)#249 (25) {
  ["id"]=&gt;
  int(1)
  ["product_name"]=&gt;
  string(6) "Cama X"
  ["store_id"]=&gt;
  int(1)
  ["quantity"]=&gt;
  int(20)
  ["description"]=&gt;
  string(9) "Muito Boa"
  ["price"]=&gt;
  float(550.5)
  ["status"]=&gt;
  int(1)
  ["created"]=&gt;
  object(Cake\I18n\Time)#244 (3) {
    ["time"]=&gt;
    string(24) "2015-07-17T00:00:00+0000"
    ["timezone"]=&gt;
    string(3) "UTC"
    ["fixedNowTime"]=&gt;
    bool(false)
  }
  ["modified"]=&gt;
  object(Cake\I18n\Time)#247 (3) {
    ["time"]=&gt;
    string(24) "2015-07-17T00:00:00+0000"
    ["timezone"]=&gt;
    string(3) "UTC"
    ["fixedNowTime"]=&gt;
    bool(false)
  }
  ["sub_category_id"]=&gt;
  int(8)
  ["sold"]=&gt;
  int(40)
  ["old_price"]=&gt;
  float(400)
  ["visited"]=&gt;
  int(777)
  ["thumbnail"]=&gt;
  string(21) "products/product2.jpg"
  ["product_medias"]=&gt;
  array(2) {
    [0]=&gt;
    object(App\Model\Entity\ProductMedia)#239 (12) {
      ["id"]=&gt;
      int(1)
      ["product_id"]=&gt;
      int(1)
      ["media_id"]=&gt;
      int(1)
      ["created"]=&gt;
      object(Cake\I18n\Time)#232 (3) {
        ["time"]=&gt;
        string(24) "2015-07-17T00:00:00+0000"
        ["timezone"]=&gt;
        string(3) "UTC"
        ["fixedNowTime"]=&gt;
        bool(false)
      }
      ["modified"]=&gt;
      object(Cake\I18n\Time)#235 (3) {
        ["time"]=&gt;
        string(24) "2015-07-17T00:00:00+0000"
        ["timezone"]=&gt;
        string(3) "UTC"
        ["fixedNowTime"]=&gt;
        bool(false)
      }
      ["[new]"]=&gt;
      bool(false)
      ["[accessible]"]=&gt;
      array(4) {
        ["product_id"]=&gt;
        bool(true)
        ["media_id"]=&gt;
        bool(true)
        ["product"]=&gt;
        bool(true)
        ["media"]=&gt;
        bool(true)
      }
      ["[dirty]"]=&gt;
      array(0) {
      }
      ["[original]"]=&gt;
      array(0) {
      }
      ["[virtual]"]=&gt;
      array(0) {
      }
      ["[errors]"]=&gt;
      array(0) {
      }
      ["[repository]"]=&gt;
      string(13) "ProductMedias"
    }
    [1]=&gt;
    object(App\Model\Entity\ProductMedia)#237 (12) {
      ["id"]=&gt;
      int(8)
      ["product_id"]=&gt;
      int(1)
      ["media_id"]=&gt;
      int(8)
      ["created"]=&gt;
      object(Cake\I18n\Time)#240 (3) {
        ["time"]=&gt;
        string(24) "2015-07-17T00:00:00+0000"
        ["timezone"]=&gt;
        string(3) "UTC"
        ["fixedNowTime"]=&gt;
        bool(false)
      }
      ["modified"]=&gt;
      object(Cake\I18n\Time)#231 (3) {
        ["time"]=&gt;
        string(24) "2015-07-17T00:00:00+0000"
        ["timezone"]=&gt;
        string(3) "UTC"
        ["fixedNowTime"]=&gt;
        bool(false)
      }
      ["[new]"]=&gt;
      bool(false)
      ["[accessible]"]=&gt;
      array(4) {
        ["product_id"]=&gt;
        bool(true)
        ["media_id"]=&gt;
        bool(true)
        ["product"]=&gt;
        bool(true)
        ["media"]=&gt;
        bool(true)
      }
      ["[dirty]"]=&gt;
      array(0) {
      }
      ["[original]"]=&gt;
      array(0) {
      }
      ["[virtual]"]=&gt;
      array(0) {
      }
      ["[errors]"]=&gt;
      array(0) {
      }
      ["[repository]"]=&gt;
      string(13) "ProductMedias"
    }
  }
  ["product_features"]=&gt;
  array(2) {
    [0]=&gt;
    object(App\Model\Entity\ProductFeature)#218 (13) {
      ["id"]=&gt;
      int(1)
      ["feature_value"]=&gt;
      string(5) "30 Cm"
      ["feature_id"]=&gt;
      int(1)
      ["product_id"]=&gt;
      int(1)
      ["created"]=&gt;
      object(Cake\I18n\Time)#211 (3) {
        ["time"]=&gt;
        string(24) "2015-07-17T00:00:00+0000"
        ["timezone"]=&gt;
        string(3) "UTC"
        ["fixedNowTime"]=&gt;
        bool(false)
      }
      ["modified"]=&gt;
      object(Cake\I18n\Time)#214 (3) {
        ["time"]=&gt;
        string(24) "2015-07-17T00:00:00+0000"
        ["timezone"]=&gt;
        string(3) "UTC"
        ["fixedNowTime"]=&gt;
        bool(false)
      }
      ["[new]"]=&gt;
      bool(false)
      ["[accessible]"]=&gt;
      array(5) {
        ["feature_value"]=&gt;
        bool(true)
        ["feature_id"]=&gt;
        bool(true)
        ["product_id"]=&gt;
        bool(true)
        ["feature"]=&gt;
        bool(true)
        ["product"]=&gt;
        bool(true)
      }
      ["[dirty]"]=&gt;
      array(0) {
      }
      ["[original]"]=&gt;
      array(0) {
      }
      ["[virtual]"]=&gt;
      array(0) {
      }
      ["[errors]"]=&gt;
      array(0) {
      }
      ["[repository]"]=&gt;
      string(15) "ProductFeatures"
    }
    [1]=&gt;
    object(App\Model\Entity\ProductFeature)#216 (13) {
      ["id"]=&gt;
      int(8)
      ["feature_value"]=&gt;
      string(5) "20 Kg"
      ["feature_id"]=&gt;
      int(2)
      ["product_id"]=&gt;
      int(1)
      ["created"]=&gt;
      object(Cake\I18n\Time)#219 (3) {
        ["time"]=&gt;
        string(24) "2015-07-17T00:00:00+0000"
        ["timezone"]=&gt;
        string(3) "UTC"
        ["fixedNowTime"]=&gt;
        bool(false)
      }
      ["modified"]=&gt;
      object(Cake\I18n\Time)#210 (3) {
        ["time"]=&gt;
        string(24) "2015-07-17T00:00:00+0000"
        ["timezone"]=&gt;
        string(3) "UTC"
        ["fixedNowTime"]=&gt;
        bool(false)
      }
      ["[new]"]=&gt;
      bool(false)
      ["[accessible]"]=&gt;
      array(5) {
        ["feature_value"]=&gt;
        bool(true)
        ["feature_id"]=&gt;
        bool(true)
        ["product_id"]=&gt;
        bool(true)
        ["feature"]=&gt;
        bool(true)
        ["product"]=&gt;
        bool(true)
      }
      ["[dirty]"]=&gt;
      array(0) {
      }
      ["[original]"]=&gt;
      array(0) {
      }
      ["[virtual]"]=&gt;
      array(0) {
      }
      ["[errors]"]=&gt;
      array(0) {
      }
      ["[repository]"]=&gt;
      string(15) "ProductFeatures"
    }
  }
  ["bookings"]=&gt;
  array(1) {
    [0]=&gt;
    object(App\Model\Entity\Booking)#196 (13) {
      ["id"]=&gt;
      int(1)
      ["product_id"]=&gt;
      int(1)
      ["quantity"]=&gt;
      int(5)
      ["user_id"]=&gt;
      int(1)
      ["created"]=&gt;
      object(Cake\I18n\Time)#194 (3) {
        ["time"]=&gt;
        string(24) "2015-07-17T00:00:00+0000"
        ["timezone"]=&gt;
        string(3) "UTC"
        ["fixedNowTime"]=&gt;
        bool(false)
      }
      ["modified"]=&gt;
      object(Cake\I18n\Time)#195 (3) {
        ["time"]=&gt;
        string(24) "2015-07-17T00:00:00+0000"
        ["timezone"]=&gt;
        string(3) "UTC"
        ["fixedNowTime"]=&gt;
        bool(false)
      }
      ["[new]"]=&gt;
      bool(false)
      ["[accessible]"]=&gt;
      array(5) {
        ["product_id"]=&gt;
        bool(true)
        ["quantity"]=&gt;
        bool(true)
        ["user_id"]=&gt;
        bool(true)
        ["product"]=&gt;
        bool(true)
        ["user"]=&gt;
        bool(true)
      }
      ["[dirty]"]=&gt;
      array(0) {
      }
      ["[original]"]=&gt;
      array(0) {
      }
      ["[virtual]"]=&gt;
      array(0) {
      }
      ["[errors]"]=&gt;
      array(0) {
      }
      ["[repository]"]=&gt;
      string(8) "Bookings"
    }
  }
  ["store"]=&gt;
  object(App\Model\Entity\Store)#243 (12) {
    ["id"]=&gt;
    int(1)
    ["store_name"]=&gt;
    string(6) "Loja A"
    ["user_id"]=&gt;
    int(1)
    ["created"]=&gt;
    object(Cake\I18n\Time)#251 (3) {
      ["time"]=&gt;
      string(24) "2015-07-17T00:00:00+0000"
      ["timezone"]=&gt;
      string(3) "UTC"
      ["fixedNowTime"]=&gt;
      bool(false)
    }
    ["modified"]=&gt;
    object(Cake\I18n\Time)#252 (3) {
      ["time"]=&gt;
      string(24) "2015-07-17T00:00:00+0000"
      ["timezone"]=&gt;
      string(3) "UTC"
      ["fixedNowTime"]=&gt;
      bool(false)
    }
    ["[new]"]=&gt;
    bool(false)
    ["[accessible]"]=&gt;
    array(4) {
      ["store_name"]=&gt;
      bool(true)
      ["user_id"]=&gt;
      bool(true)
      ["user"]=&gt;
      bool(true)
      ["products"]=&gt;
      bool(true)
    }
    ["[dirty]"]=&gt;
    array(0) {
    }
    ["[original]"]=&gt;
    array(0) {
    }
    ["[virtual]"]=&gt;
    array(0) {
    }
    ["[errors]"]=&gt;
    array(0) {
    }
    ["[repository]"]=&gt;
    string(6) "Stores"
  }
  ["[new]"]=&gt;
  bool(false)
  ["[accessible]"]=&gt;
  array(10) {
    ["product_name"]=&gt;
    bool(true)
    ["store_id"]=&gt;
    bool(true)
    ["quantity"]=&gt;
    bool(true)
    ["description"]=&gt;
    bool(true)
    ["price"]=&gt;
    bool(true)
    ["status"]=&gt;
    bool(true)
    ["store"]=&gt;
    bool(true)
    ["bookings"]=&gt;
    bool(true)
    ["product_features"]=&gt;
    bool(true)
    ["product_medias"]=&gt;
    bool(true)
  }
  ["[dirty]"]=&gt;
  array(0) {
  }
  ["[original]"]=&gt;
  array(0) {
  }
  ["[virtual]"]=&gt;
  array(0) {
  }
  ["[errors]"]=&gt;
  array(0) {
  }
  ["[repository]"]=&gt;
  string(8) "Products"
}
```

Comment: @ErlonCharles este `$this->Products->get()` vei por padrão com o a geração do arquivo pela `bake`

Comment: Estava procurando o recursive na documentação do 3, como ficaria o find sem ele então?

Comment: Posta o resultado do seu `$this->Products->get()` pra eu analisar, porque de acordo com a documentação era pra retornar seus `product_features` também. mas se quiser pode tentar esse *find* `$this->Products->find('first', [
 'conditions' => ['Products.id' => $id],
 'contain' => ['Stores', 'Bookings', 'ProductFeatures', 'ProductMedias']
]);`

Comment: $this->Products->get() da erro de falta de parametro

Comment: @ErlonCharles não funcionou a segunda abordagem, tive até de modificar pois o 'first' não é mais suportado, tive de fazer um `->first()`

Comment: Entendi, ainda me confundo entre as coisas do cake2 e do cake3, mas posta o que tem no seu `$product` original.

Comment: @ErlonCharles fiz um var_dump no resultado a minha primeira query e o resultado foi enorme há alguma forma de posta-lo fora do site (por causa do tamanho)? vou tentar reduzir minha pergunta para inserilo

Comment: @ErlonCharles adicionei o resultado do var_dump

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26662/discussion-between-erlon-charles-and-ricardo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No seu retorno você possui `feature_id` na sua `product_features`, portanto para cada resultado da `product_features` faça um `get()`

```
$this->loadModel('Features')
foreach ($product['product_features'] as $product_feature){;
    $recentFeatures[] = $this->Features->get($product_feature['feature_id']);
}

$product['features'] = $recentFeatures;
```

`loadModel()` serve para te permitir usar um model que não foi carregado neste *controller* nessa *action* especifica, assim você não precisa carregar um Model que não será utilizado em todas as *actions* do seu *controller* e reduz o tempo de resposta das páginas